# Plotly Selection Events Scatter Plot: No Update of Data on Mouse Selection

Tags: python, plot, ipython, plotly, jupyter

On a scatter plot I want to be able to select an area and then to update a table below displaying the data points in that area. Like done by [Selection Events by Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/selection-events/).

I have already adapted the example but nothing happens on a Mouse Selection. The data gets initially shown (all the data) but it does not update. When I use pdb in the update function `selection_fn` I see that it never goes to it when I select an area with the Mouse .
I also followed [this thread from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827778/plotly-failed-to-return-information-for-selected-data-points-for-multiple-tracer) but it does not change anything. Neither of the two approaches give an error and show the scatter graph with the initial table of all data.

This is my code, adapted from the Plotly tutorial:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import plotly.offline as po
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interactive, HBox, VBox
po.init_notebook_mode()
import time
import pdb

f = FigureWidget([Scatter(y = plot_data["t-SNE-X"], x = plot_data["t-SNE-Y"], mode = 'markers')])
scatter = f.data[0]

N = len(plot_data)
scatter.x = scatter.x + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(plot_data['t-SNE-X'].max() - plot_data['t-SNE-X'].min())
scatter.y = scatter.y + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(plot_data['t-SNE-Y'].max() - plot_data['t-SNE-Y'].min())
scatter.marker.opacity = 0.5

def update_axes(xaxis, yaxis):
    scatter = f.data[0]
    scatter.x = plot_data[xaxis]
    scatter.y = plot_data[yaxis]
    with f.batch_update():
        f.layout.xaxis.title = xaxis
        f.layout.yaxis.title = yaxis
        scatter.x = scatter.x + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(plot_data[xaxis].max() - plot_data[xaxis].min())
        scatter.y = scatter.y + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(plot_data[yaxis].max() - plot_data[yaxis].min())

axis_dropdowns = interactive(update_axes, yaxis = plot_data.select_dtypes('int64').columns, xaxis = plot_data.select_dtypes('int64').columns)

# Create a table FigureWidget that updates on selection from points in the scatter plot of f
t = FigureWidget([Table(
    header=dict(values=plot_data.columns,
                fill = dict(color='#C2D4FF'),
                align = ['left'] * 5),

    cells=dict(values=[plot_data[col] for col in plot_data.columns],

               fill = dict(color='#F5F8FF'),
               align = ['left'] * 5
               ))])

 def selection_fn(trace,points,selector):
     t.data[0].cells.values = [plot_data.loc[points.point_inds][col] for col in plot_data.columns]

scatter.on_selection(selection_fn)



#iplot({data : scatter.on_selection(selection_fn)})

# Put everything together
VBox((f, t))
```

This is what I see (blurred because of privacy):
[image: Plotyly scatter graph with failed mouse selection]

Answer (score 2):

Just for the next person running into the same issue - remember that the default behavior when you select a region on a plotly figure is to zoom in to it.

So, in order to trigger your own on_selection function, just toggle either the "Box Select" or "Lasso Select" icon from the built-in controls of your figure. You don't need to hardcode it as the previous answer seem to indicate.

Comment: that's correct, it took me some times to dicover it as well.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of debugging I found out, that this code now works on plotly 3.7.1 and that the line `f.layout.dragmode = 'lasso'` was missing, which is nowhere documented.