# "Point Select" mode in plotly interactive figure

Tags: python, plotly, click, scatter

I am trying to adapt [this plotly script example](https://plotly.com/python/v3/selection-events/), allowing to populate a table using a plotly mouse selection event. I am running this piece of code in a Jupyter notebook.

As pointed [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290864/plotly-selection-events-scatter-plot-no-update-of-data-on-mouse-selection):

> ...in order to trigger your own on_selection function, just toggle
> either the "Box Select" or "Lasso Select" icon from the built-in
> controls of your figure.*

[image]

I am indeed able to update the table using either the "Box Select" or the "Lasso Select" by toggling the relevant button in the interactive figure, but how would I activate a "Point Select"? I would like to select a single point in the scatter plot by simply clicking on it.